# How to fix "xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576" showing in dmesg?

Tags: networking, 18.04, dmesg

Ubuntu 18.04
Bash 4.4.0

The command `dmesg -T` shows the following over and over again:

```
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: size too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
[Wed Jul  7 18:24:50 2021] xt_hashlimit: max too large, truncated to 1048576
```

Where can I set this so this message does not appear any longer?

Comment: It looks like this is likely related to the `hashlimit` [iptables extension](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html). Do you recall configuring such an iptables rule?

Comment: @steeldriver In my `/etc/rc.local` file I do load /sbin/modprobe xt_recent
`/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack`, `/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp`.